# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in my own shell in c

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to write my own simple shell in c.
When I type a command in the shell(e.g. ls) I get Segmentation fault(core dumped).
Maybe the problem is in the arguements in main?

I cannot find where the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512



char *readline(void){

    char* line;
    if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)){
        exit;
    }
    size_t length=strlen(line);
    if (line[length-1]== '\n'){
        line[length-1]='\0';
    }
    if(strcmp(line, "exit") ==0){
        exit;
    }
    return line;
}



char **split_line(char *line){
    char* tokens[100];
    char* token;
    int i=0;

    token=strtok(line," ");

    while( token !=NULL){
        tokens[i] = token;
        token=strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    tokens[i]=NULL;
    return tokens;
}



int exec_line(char **args){
    pid_t pid, wpid;
    char path[40];
    int status;

    strcpy(path, "/bin/");
    strcat(path, args[0]);

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        if (execvp(path, args)== -1){
            printf("Child process could not do execvp \n");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }else{
        do{
            wpid=waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        }while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }
    return 1;

}


void lloop(void){
        char *line;
        char **args;
        int status;

        do{
                printf("my_shell> ");
                line=readline();
                args=split_line(line);
                status=exec_line(args);

                free(line);
                free(args);
        }while(status);
}


int main(){

        lloop();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `char* line; if(!fgets(line, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)) ...` no memory allocated... crash.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/pcf). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: BTW `exit;` is a syntax error. It needs to be something like `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` Was this even your code?

Answer (score 0):

**problem 1:** you can't write `exit;` instead of `exit();`

**problem 2:** in the *split line* function you write

`while( token !=NULL){
tokens[i] = token;
token=strtok(NULL, " ");}`

without promote `i`

**problem 3:** in the *exec_line* function you write `strcat(path, args[0]);`

when `args` is a pointer to a 'string', not a real 'string'.

**problem 4:** never use *free* on a pointer that you didn't gave him a *malloc*.

the *malloc* function also write in the saved place things for the _free _function.

this is an *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What do you mean by "without promote `i`"? Did you mean that `i` was never incremented to index the next array element?

Comment: i mean without `i++`